# Can't access form data in the put route

Tags: node.js, forms, express

When I submit the form req.body keeps coming back empty.

Form:

```
<form
  action="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>/reviews/<%= review._id %>?_method=PUT"
  method="POST"
  novalidate
  class="validated-form"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
   <label for="body" class="form-label">Review: </label>
   <input
     type="text"
     class="form-control"
     id="body"
     name="review[body]"
     required
     value="<%= review.body %>"
   />
   <button class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
</form>
```

I am also using this middleware

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

This is the route I hit

```
router.put(
   "/:id",
   catchAsync(reviews.editReview)
   );
```

This is the editReview function

```
  const { id } = req.params;
  const review = await Review.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { ...req.body.review });
  await review.save();
```

Comment: Can you show your editReview function in full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

body-parser (express.json is body-parser.json) doesn't support multipart/form-data you can fix this by using multer

```
npm install multer
```

and in app.js

```
const multer = require('multer');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(multer().array());
```